# How to track: C:\S3\S3\HauteurS3.c|178|warning: 'fArray_I_I_I_lsm.241' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]|

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I pre-defined an array:`float fArray[14][355*4][1];/* to save data for Plot.csv */`
It has worked for some time but now I need to track this warning because I see`||=== Build failed: 0 error(s), 8 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|`

Line 178: is merely "int main( void)"

I cannot track where the compiler (gcc 4.9.2) detects the error since the "fArray_I_I_I_lsm.262" seems meaningless. The "_lsm.262" is not a relevant line number in my code.
There are eight similar warnings, only the "_lsm.2xx" number changes.

It's the "build failed" which is of concern though the program partially works as programmed, i.e. it does seem to build

Comment: @Vadim Kotov In my post gcc 4.9.2. Code written in C for 32 bit Windows.

Comment: OK but I'm still stuck with this error. Even trying to attempt float fArray[14][355*4][1] = {0,0,0}; removes the eight warnings but raises a new one : >136|warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]|< and using memset() the "build failed" message still stays.